# Red dot (circle) next to the app name below the app icon on the iPhone Home Screen on iOS 8

Tags: ios, icons, ios-app-extension, homescreen

What does the red dot (circle) next to the app name below the app icon mean?

[image]

I added a Today Extension (Widget) to the app. It appears only when I launch the app on the iOS 8, it does not appear on iOS 7 simulator. Even though I removed the extension and cleared the simulator, it still appears before the app name.

Comment: Did you figure out what its purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Red dot next to app title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372864/red-dot-next-to-app-title)

Answer (score 71):

An Orange dot next to an app normally means it's a beta version, as installed through Testflight. I have a couple of those at the moment, though one looks more red. Trying to find if there's a difference between an orange and a red dot, or if it's just an artefact of the colour of the background image that makes it look red.

Comment: Here is the final word on this that supports Phil's answer:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/TestFlightFAQ.pdf

Comment: Yes it says on page 6 "Beta apps will be indicated with an orange dot next to the app name on your device." But there are devices I install beta Apps and the orange dot do not appear...

Comment: Is there a way to hide it? Since I'm a developer it bugs me looking at all these dots that are breaking app names :) and I like having latest beta versions on my phone.

Comment: Yes @PhilBowman, what I found on other links is, the light and dark colour depends on the background on Home Screen.

Answer (score 39):

The dot you see is actually an orange dot, with transparency. On dark backgrounds it seems like it's red. Try changing to a bright background.

Comment: Thats it... it looks red on black background.

Comment: the question is what does the dot mean rather than the importance of the color.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the correct answer for the question is Phil Bowman's ;)

Comment: this is untrue. i have both colors on the background

Answer (score 5):

Orange dots for all beta apps that are downloaded from TestFlight and blue dots for recently updated apps from App Store.

Comment: I would add that the blue dot also appears right after installing new build from TestFlight, after opening it will become orange.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question @user5673323221, and the answer by @PhilBowman. As apart from the red colour, there are few more colours as well such as yellow and blue having their specific meaning.

Check this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@mohitG./different-colour-indicators-under-ios-app-25c571171179?sk=59230cc0ebf231b057c685df70718bef) for them all.