# Red dot next to app title?

Tags: ios, iphone, icons, ios-simulator

On the simulator I have noticed that my app has a red circle next to the app title, similar to the blue circle that appears next to newly downloaded apps, however just red instead.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

What does this imply?

Comment: It implies that you updated the app and haven't opened it yet.

Comment: @CarouselMin That's odd, it does not disappear if i quit and then open the app. I have done it several times. Could the simulator be glitching?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using? Wondering if a new version of Xcode or iOS is using that to indicate backwards incompatibility or some other issue like that? Just guessing, though.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg I think it has to do with the version/build number of the app itself. It only happened after I changed the version/build. But when it happens it's seemingly impossible to get rid of the dot. I still have no clue as to what it is supposed to imply.

Comment: Might be a good post for devforums.apple.com

Comment: @ZevEisenberg I actually posted this question to the devforums before posting to stackoverflow. No luck yet though.

Comment: The orange dot on your device's home screen - indicate it's a test build. In iTunes Connect check the “Prerelease” Tab….

Comment: I have the same problem. My solution is i change the "Code Signing Identity" under Built Settings to a another profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the Actual Solution for this problem it is due to provisioning Profile. if you are using live app provisioning profile in your app Build setting , change it and after that you will never see that orange circle.

Comment: How can I differentialte live provisioning profile and beta provisioning profile?

Answer (score 4):

If to believe to other answers here, there might be several reasons for this red dot.

In my case, the reason appears in TestFlight's [docs](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/TestFlightFAQ.pdf):

> **How will I know which apps on my device are beta apps?**
>  Beta apps
>   will be indicated with an orange dot next to the app name on your
>   device.

Got a lead for finding this thanks to Ashish's comment to one of the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the red dot near an app name indicates that you enabled some capability (for example HealthKit) in the 'Capabilities' menu of your target, which isn't allowed for your app ID. It appears only on iOS 8+ simulators.

If so, you also will see this red sign in 'Capabilities' menu:
[image: 'Capabilities' menu]

You need to go to [Apple developers portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action) and enable capability you need for your app ID.

If after that you still got red dot in springboard and red sign in 'Capabilities', try to go to 
Preferences -> Accounts -> Double click your account -> refresh button.
I got rid of mysterious red dot after this.