# Red dot before app name ios simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

Please can anyone explain why my app in simulator has a red dot before app name on home screen?I read that it may be different information in capability in app xcode and in app id in developer.com. But information is the same.

Comment: Сергей, сделай скриншот!

Comment: @Sulthan
[link](http://s018.radikal.ru/i510/1411/81/d9972be7f878.png)

Comment: @Andy
[link](http://s018.radikal.ru/i510/1411/81/d9972be7f878.png)

Comment: Weird. Usually there is a "new app" indicator in there, but it's blue. Do you have Debug -> Color Blended Layers turned on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Red dot next to app title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372864/red-dot-next-to-app-title)